# JQuery tooltip not displaying

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I'm trying to set a tooltip for some listed elements using jquery ui but I can't get the tooltips to show. I'm trying to apply a tooltip to all items using the tooltip class. Please check my code for problems...

HTML

```
<li>
<label>
  <input id="someid" type="radio" name="name" />
  <strong><span>text</span></strong></label>
  <a href="#" class="tooltip" title="some text"></a>
  <h4>text</h4>
</li>
```

JS

```
function showTooltip() {
$("#tooltip").each(function()
    {
        $(this).tooltip();
    };
};
```

Thanks :)

Comment: You should try to use a class instead of an ID in this case. Valid HTML doesn't allow duplicate ID's for elements.

Comment: Also you're tooltip is a class and you're referencing an id `$('.tooltip').....`

Comment: Like 'romo' mentioned your code should look like this: function showTooltip() {
$(".tooltip").each(function()
    {
        $(this).tooltip();
    };
};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function must have a class selector: $(".class")... not $("#id")

```
$(function(){
    showTooltip();
    function showTooltip() {
       $(".tooltip").each(function() {
           $(this).tooltip();
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: Doh! I believe this is the answer, but I still can't get it to show.

Comment: Did you you call that function on document ready? The example at JQueryUI.com calls it on document ready....
And be sure to import jQuery.js, jquery-ui.js, and jquery-ui.css

Comment: It wasn't in document.ready but it is now. It's still not showing up. Maybe it's out of focus. idk... It seemed so simple in the api documentation, but this is frustrating!

Comment: You can use  a class or id selector with the tooltip function

Answer (score 24):

For anyone else struggling with tooltip not working.

I have found a number of issues with jquery-ui as of late, however it seems they did not handle null input of the default item content.

Thus by default it is 'title' so if you did not enter a title attribute to the element you want to make the tooltip object it will fail even if you specify the content like so:

```
$("#element").tooltip({content:"test"});
```

It's pretty weak not to handle null(or undefined) values in my opinion but that's how it is.

I handled it by adding a title attribute like so to the element:

```
title=''
```

I guess you could specify a `items` in the tooltip constructer like so:

```
$("#selector").tooltip({items:'other-title', content: 'test'});
```

But then you would still need to add the new attribute to the element like so:

```
other-title=''
```

PS: using JQuery-UI 1.11.4

Comment: that was a sneaky one

Comment: Exceedingly disappointing. If they have a `content` option for setting the content, why do I have _still_ have to use `title` in the HTML? 

Comment: JQuery-UI dpoesn't bother me anymore because I no longer use it anywhere.  If I need a dialog box for example, I create it from scratch.

Comment: Thanks! I also needed an empty title attribute for the display.

Comment: Excellent response.  I couldn't agree with you more in not handling null titles! This helped me solving several wasted hours.

Answer (score 7):

Try using:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).tooltip();
});
```

so everything with `title="yourtitle"` in it will have a jquery tooltip when you hover over it.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/uD9en/)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem occurred because Bootstrap was also loaded on the page.

Answer (score 0):

when I used $(document).tooltip(); , It made tooltip for every element, to get tooltip for specific I used,

```
    $(function () {
      $(document).tooltip({
          track: true, 
          items: ".tooltip",
          content: function () {
              return $(this).attr("title");
          }
      });
  });
```

Comment: just by $(document).tooltip(); did not work for me. I had to do it for specific element where I needed to add items: "#id", to get specific, so just I wanted to share

Answer (score 0):

Like others are saying, all you should need is the following:

```
$(document).tooltip();
```

But there are exceptions where this alone will just not work.  Specific cases where this will not work:

- `option` elements within a `select` block. (tooltip displays underneath the select option)
- `disabled="true"` elements will continue to display tooltips in non-jQuery-UI format until re-enabled.

Besides reprogramming jQuery-UI, I have found no real solution to these problems.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing I want to show a tooltip on an input, I can do it using the HTMl attribute "title" as:

```
`<input type="text" id="an_id" style="width: 120px" title='Tooltip on an_id'>`
```

Hovering the mouse pointer over the element would show the message contained within the title tag as a tooltip.

Likewise, it is also possible to add a tooltip using the attribute "title' on a cell ('TD') of an HTML table using jQuery.

A use case may be multiple inputs displayed in cells within an HTML table:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('mouseover', '#my_table td', function() {
        $("#input1").attr('title', 'Tooltip 1 using jQuery');
        $("#input2").attr('title', 'Tooltip 2 using jQuery');
    });
});
```

We may further extend the functionality in other ways too, eg. to dynamically added table rows.